# Handler vs AsyncTask vs Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-handler

I got slightly confused about the differences between `Handlers`, `AsyncTask` and `Threads` in Android. I've read quite a few blogs and questions here in StackOverflow.

`Handler` are background threads that provide you to communicate with the UI. Updating a progress bar, for instance, should be done via `Handler`. Using Handlers you have the advantage of `MessagingQueues`, so if you want to schedule messages or update multiple UI elements or have repeating tasks.

`AsyncTask` are similar, in fact, they make use of `Handler`, but doesn't run in the UI thread, so it's good for fetching data, for instance fetching web services. Later you can interact with the UI.

`Thread` however can't interact with the UI, provide more "basic" threading and you miss all the abstractions of `AsyncTask`.

However, I would like to have a socket connection run in service. Should this be run in a handler or a thread, or even an `AsyncTask`? UI interaction is not necessary at all. Does it make a difference in terms of performance which I use?

Meanwhile, the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) has been majorly improved.

Comment: Worth checking out: [Douglas Schmidt lecture android concurrency and synchronisation](https://www.google.com/search?q=lecture%208%20android%20concurrency%20and%20synchronisation)

Comment: "Handlers are background threads" -- Some of the top-voted answers seem to go into that direction too. But that's a misconception. A `Handler` is not a thread, and it doesn't execute anything. It is only a means to safely pass messages from one *thread* to the message queue of another *thread*. So, normally, (at least) two threads must still be created which can then *use* a handler, but the handler cannot execute anything itself.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

As the Tutorial on [Android background processing with Handlers, AsyncTask and Loaders](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_handler) on the Vogella site puts it:

The `Handler` class can be used to register to a thread and provides a simple channel to send data to this thread.

The `AsyncTask` class encapsulates the creation of a background process and the synchronization with the main thread. It also supports reporting progress of the running tasks.

And a `Thread` is basically the core element of multithreading which a developer can use with the following disadvantage:

> If you use Java threads you have to handle the following requirements
>   in your own code:
>
> - Synchronization with the main thread if you post back results to the user interface
> - No default for canceling the thread
> - No default thread pooling
> - No default for handling configuration changes in Android

And regarding the `AsyncTask`, as the [Android Developer's Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) puts it:

> `AsyncTask` enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class
>   allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI
>   thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.
>
> `AsyncTask` is designed to be a helper class around `Thread` and `Handler`
>   and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks
>   should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the
>   most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time,
>   it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the
>   java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and
>   FutureTask.

**Update May 2015:** I found an **excellent series of lectures** covering this topic.

> This is the Google Search: [Douglas Schmidt lecture android concurrency and synchronisation](https://www.google.com/search?q=lecture%208%20android%20concurrency%20and%20synchronisation)
>
> This is the video of the [first lecture on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aV2XfWwpiDU)
>
> All this is part of the **CS 282 (2013): Systems Programming for Android** from the **Vanderbilt University**. Here's the [YouTube Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZ9NgFYEMxp50tvT8806xllaCbd31DpDy)
>
> Douglas Schmidt seems to be an excellent lecturer

**Important:** If you are at a point where you are considering to use `AsyncTask` to solve your threading issues, you should first **check out [`ReactiveX/RxAndroid`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid#rxandroid-reactive-extensions-for-android)** for a possibly more appropriate programming pattern. A very good resource for getting an overview is [Learning RxJava 2 for Android by example](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/RxJava2-Android-Samples#learning-rxjava-2-for-android-by-example).

Comment: In that lecture series, this link will take you right into some thread examples:
https://youtu.be/4Vue_KuXfCk?t=19m24s

Answer (score 359):

If we look at the source code, we will see `AsyncTask` and `Handler` is purely written in Java. (There are some exceptions, though. But that is not an important point)

So there is no magic in `AsyncTask` or `Handler`. These classes make our life easier as a developer.

For example: If Program A calls method A(), method A() could run in a different thread with Program A. We can easily verify by following code:

```
Thread t = Thread.currentThread();    
int id = t.getId();
```

Why should we use a new thread for some tasks? You can google for it. Many many reasons,e.g: lifting heavily, long-running works.

So, what are the differences between `Thread`, `AsyncTask`, and `Handler`?

`AsyncTask` and `Handler` are written in Java (internally they use a `Thread`), so everything we can do with `Handler` or `AsyncTask`, we can achieve using a `Thread` too.

What can `Handler` and `AsyncTask` really help?

The most obvious reason is communication between the caller thread and the worker thread.
(**Caller Thread**: A thread which calls the **Worker Thread** to perform some tasks. A caller thread doesn't necessarily have to be the UI thread). Of course, we can communicate between two threads in other ways, but there are many disadvantages (and dangers) because of thread safety.

That is why we should use `Handler` and `AsyncTask`. These classes do most of the work for us, we only need to know which methods to override.

The difference between `Handler` and `AsyncTask` is: Use `AsyncTask` when *Caller thread* is a *UI Thread*.
This is what android document says:

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class
>   allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI
>   thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers

I want to emphasize two points:

1) Easy use of the UI thread (so, use when caller thread is UI Thread).

2) No need to manipulate handlers. (means: You can use Handler instead of AsyncTask, but AsyncTask is an easier option).

There are many things in this post I haven't said yet, for example: what is UI Thread, or why it's easier. You must know some methods behind each class and use it, you will completely understand the reason why.

@: when you read the Android document, you will see:

> Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects
>   associated with a thread's MessageQueue

This description might seem strange at first. We only need to understand that each thread has each message queue (like a to-do list), and the thread will take each message and do it until the message queue is empty (just like we finish our work and go to bed). So, when `Handler` communicates, it just gives a message to caller thread and it will wait to process.

Complicated? Just remember that `Handler` can communicate with the caller thread safely.

Comment: actually asynctask is also based on handler and futuretask, [see](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java#L327)

Comment: AsyncTask is essentially a helper class built on top of Handler and Thread. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. Look at the doc "AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler ". AsyncTask is released in API3 while Handler exists since API1.

Answer (score 57):

After looking in-depth, it's straight forward.

**`AsyncTask`:**

It's a simple way to use a thread *without knowing anything about the java thread model*.
`AsyncTask` gives various callbacks respective to the worker thread and main thread.

Use for small waiting operations like the following:

1. Fetching some data from web services and display over the layout.
2. Database query.
3. When you realize that running operation will never, ever be nested.

**`Handler`:**

When we install an application in android, then it creates a thread for that application called MAIN UI Thread.  All activities run inside that thread.  By the android single thread model rule, we can not access UI elements (bitmap, textview, etc..) directly for another thread defined inside that activity.

A Handler allows you to communicate back with the UI thread from other background threads. This is useful in android as android doesn’t allow other threads to communicate directly with UI thread. A handler can send and process Message and Runnable objects associated with a thread’s MessageQueue. Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread’s message queue. When a new Handler is created, it is bound to the thread/message queue of the thread that is creating it.

It's the best fit for:

1. It allows you to do message queuing.
2. Message scheduling.

**`Thread`:**

Now it's time to talk about the thread.

Thread is the parent of both `AsyncTask` and `Handler`. They both internally use thread, which means **you can also create your own thread model** like `AsyncTask` and `Handler`, but that requires a good knowledge of **Java's Multi-Threading Implementation**.

Comment: AsyncTask api is, in fact, written with Futures, Handlers, and Executors.  See source code: http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/os/AsyncTask.java/?v=source

Answer (score 22):

An `AsyncTask` is used to do some background computation and publish the result to the UI thread (with optional progress updates). Since you're not concerned with UI, then a `Handler` or `Thread` seems more appropriate.

You can spawn a background `Thread` and pass messages back to your main thread by using the  `Handler`'s `post` method.

Answer (score 9):

[Thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)

Android supports standard Java *Threads*. You can use standard Threads and the tools from the package “`java.util.concurrent`” to put actions into the background. The only limitation is that you cannot directly update the UI from the a background process.

If you need to update the UI from a background task you need to use some Android specific classes. You can use the class “`android.os.Handler`” for this or the class “`AsyncTask`”

[Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

The class “`Handler`” can update the UI. A handle provides methods for receiving messages and for runnables. To use a handler you have to subclass it and override `handleMessage()` to process messages. To process `Runable`, you can use the method `post();` You only need one instance of a handler in your activity.

You thread can post messages via the method `sendMessage(Message msg)` or `sendEmptyMessage`.

[AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

If you have an `Activity` which needs to download content or perform operations that can be done in the background `AsyncTask` allows you to maintain a responsive user interface and publish progress for those operations to the user.

For more information you can have a look at these links.

http://mobisys.in/blog/2012/01/android-threads-handlers-and-asynctask-tutorial/

http://www.slideshare.net/HoangNgoBuu/android-thread-handler-and-asynctask

Answer (score 8):

`Thread`:

You can use the new `Thread` for long-running background tasks without impacting UI Thread. From java Thread, you can't update UI Thread.

Since normal [Thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) is not much useful for Android architecture, helper classes for threading have been introduced.

You can find answers to your queries in [Threading performance](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/threads.html) documentation page.

[Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html):

A `Handler` allows you to send and process Message and `Runnable` objects associated with a thread's `MessageQueue`. Each `Handler` instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue.

There are two main uses for a `Handler`:

1. To schedule messages and runnables to be executed as some point in the future;
2. To enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own.

[AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

`AsyncTask` enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows you to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

**Drawbacks:**

1. By default, an app pushes all of the `AsyncTask` objects it creates into a single thread. Therefore, they execute in serial fashion, and—as with the main thread—an especially long work packet can block the queue. Due to this reason,  use AsyncTask to handle work items shorter than **5ms in duration**.
2. `AsyncTask` objects are also the most common offenders for implicit-reference issues. `AsyncTask` objects present risks related to explicit references, as well.

[HandlerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html):

You may need a more traditional approach to executing a block of work on a long-running thread (*unlike AsyncTask, which should be used for 5ms workload*), and some ability to manage that workflow manually.  A handler thread is effectively a long-running thread that grabs work from a queue and operates on it.

[ThreadPoolExecutor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html):

This class manages the creation of a group of threads, sets their priorities, and manages how work is distributed among those threads. As workload increases or decreases, the class spins up or destroys more threads to adjust to the workload.

If the workload is more and single `HandlerThread` is not suffice, you can go for `ThreadPoolExecutor`

> However I would like to have a socket connection run in service. Should this be run in a handler or a thread, or even an AsyncTask? UI interaction is not necessary at all. Does it make a difference in terms of performance which I use?

Since UI interaction is not required, you may not go for `AsyncTask`. Normal threads are not much useful and hence `HandlerThread` is the best option. Since you have to maintain socket connection, Handler on the main thread is not useful at all. Create a `HandlerThread` and get a `Handler` from the looper of `HandlerThread`.

```
 HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("SocketOperation");
 handlerThread.start();
 Handler requestHandler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
 requestHandler.post(myRunnable); // where myRunnable is your Runnable object.
```

If you want to communicate back to UI thread, you can use one more Handler to process response.

```
final Handler responseHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            //txtView.setText((String) msg.obj);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Foreground task is completed:"+(String)msg.obj,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    };
```

in your `Runnable`, you can add

```
responseHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

More details about implementation can be found here:

[Android: Toast in a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134683/android-toast-in-a-thread/45922317#45922317)

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion threads aren't the most efficient way of doing socket connections but they do provide the most functionality in terms of running threads. I say that because from experience, running threads for a long time causes devices to be very hot and resource intensive. Even a simple `while(true)` will heat a phone in minutes. If you say that UI interaction is not important, perhaps an `AsyncTask` is good because they are designed for long-term processes. This is just my opinion on it.

**UPDATE**

**Please disregard my above answer!** I answered this question back in 2011 when I was far less experienced in Android than I am now. My answer above is misleading and is considered wrong. I'm leaving it there because many people commented on it below correcting me, and I've learned my lesson.

There are far better other answers on this thread, but I will at least give me more proper answer. There is nothing wrong with using a regular Java `Thread`; however, you should really be careful about how you implement it because doing it wrong can be very processor intensive (most notable symptom can be your device heating up). `AsyncTask`s are pretty ideal for most tasks that you want to run in the background (common examples are disk I/O, network calls, and database calls). However, `AsyncTask`s shouldn't be used for particularly long processes that may need to continue after the user has closed your app or put their device to standby. I would say for most cases, anything that doesn't belong in the UI thread, can be taken care of in an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: thanks, is there actually a reason I should use Threads instead of AsyncTasks? Or is it more recommended to make use of it?

Comment: Well it seems that you partly understand AsyncTasks yourself. AsyncTasks are particularly useful for long-term and processor intensive tasks. You could use a Thread, which is what I used on first app that used sockets, but from experience, I've found that Threads are very processor intensive for the amount of work they are intended to do. This might not be the correct reason, but AsyncTasks seem more optimized for Android than just bare-bone Threads.

Comment: @AeroDroid In your example: "a simple while(true)", you will peg the CPU here unless you add a sleep state in the loop.  This is true of any endless loop.  If you want to reduce CPU usage due to this overhead, sleep the thread for a few milliseconds at the end of the loop.

Comment: @Error 454 - that is interesting! If you had to pick an appropriate number for the sleep time, would it be between 40-80 milliseconds?

Comment: @Abhijit From the game stuff I've done in SDL, simply adding a 10 ms sleep to the loop was enough to drop from 99% cpu to ~0 during idle states.

Comment: Actually http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html says: "AsyncTasks should ideally be used for SHORT operations". You should also use them carefully since they can be dismissed by the system without executing!

Comment: "threads aren't the most efficient way of doing socket connections" - Yes, they are. Always use *blocking* IO (no polling!) in your thread and you're as resource efficient as you'll ever get. (To still optimize a little further you can use [NIO's channels](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html) to efficiently handle multiple connections in a single thread at the same time, but still: You must use blocking IO.)

Comment: ~"**perhaps an AsyncTask is good because they are designed for long-term processes**".  The total opposite is true!

Comment: @type-a1pha it's not against Asynctask. I think this is thread's problem that used in Asynctask internally.

Answer (score 5):

`AsyncTask` is designed to perform not more than few seconds operation to be done in background (not recommended for megabytes of file downloading from server or compute cpu intensive task such as file IO operations ). If you need to execute a long running operation,  you have been  strongly advised to use java native threads. Java gives you various thread related classes to do what you need. Use `Handler` to  update the UI Thread.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class RequestHandler {

    public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL,
                                  HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

        URL url;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);


            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                String response;
                while ((response = br.readLine()) != null){
                    sb.append(response);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends which one to chose is based on the requirement

**Handler** is mostly  used to switch from  other thread to main thread, Handler is attached to a looper on which it post its runnable task in queue.
So If you are already in other thread and switch to main thread then you need handle instead of async task or other thread

If Handler created in other than main thread which is not a looper is will not give error as  handle is created the  thread, that thread  need to be made a lopper

**AsyncTask** is used to execute code for few seconds which run on background thread and gives its result to main thread 
** ***AsyncTask Limitations**
1. Async Task is not  attached to life cycle of activity and it keeps run even if its activity destroyed whereas loader doesn't have this limitation 
2. All Async Tasks share the same background thread for execution which also impact  the app performance

**Thread** is used in app for background  work also but it doesn't have any call back on main thread.
If requirement suits some threads instead of one thread and which need to give task many times  then thread pool executor is better option.Eg Requirement of   Image loading from multiple url like glide.

Answer (score 1):

*Let me try and answer the question here with an example :) - MyImageSearch [Kindly refer the image here of the main activity screen - containing an edit text / search button / grid view]*

[image: MyImageSearch]

**Description of MyImageSearch** - *Once user enters the details on the edit text field and clicks on the search button, we will search images on the internet via the web services provided by flickr (you only need to register there to get a key/secret token) - for searching we send an HTTP Request and GET JSON Data back in response containing the url's of individual images which we will then use to load the grid view.*

**My Implementation** - *In the main activity I will define a inner class which extends the AsyncTask to send the HTTP Request in doInBackGround Method and fetch the JSON Response and update my local ArrayList of FlickrItems which I am going to use to update my GridView via the FlickrAdapter (extends the BaseAdapter) and call the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in the onPostExecute() of AsyncTask to reload the grid view. Note that here the HTTP Request is a blocking call because of which I have done it via the AsyncTask. And, I can cache the items in adapter to increase the performance or store them on SDCard. The grid that I will be inflating in the FlickrAdapter contains in my implementation a progressbar and image view. Below you can find the code for mainActivity which I used.*

**Answer to the Question Now** - 
So once we have the JSON data for fetching individual Images we can implement the logic of getting the images in background via Handlers or Threads or AsyncTask. We should note here that since my images once downloaded must be displayed on the UI/main thread we cannot simply use threads as it is since they don't have access to the context.
In the FlickrAdapter, the choices I could think of:

- Choice 1: Create a LooperThread [extends thread] - and keep on
  downloading images sequentially in one thread by keeping this thread
  open [looper.loop()]
- Choice 2: Make use of a Thread Pool and post the runnable via myHandler which
  contains reference to my ImageView, but since the views in Grid View
  are recycled, again the problem might arise where image at index 4 is
  displayed at index 9 [download may take more time]
- *Choice 3 [I used this]: Make use of a Thread Pool and send a message to myHandler, which contains data related to ImageView's index and
  ImageView itself, so while doing handleMessage() we will update the
  ImageView only if currentIndex matches the index of the Image we
  tried to download.*
- Choice 4: Make use of AsyncTask to download the
  images in background, but here I will not have access to the number of threads I want in 
  the thread pool and it varies with different android version, but in Choice 3 I can make of conscious decision of the size of thread pool depending on device configuration being used.

Here the source code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    GridView imageGridView;
    ArrayList<FlickrItem> items = new ArrayList<FlickrItem>();
    FlickrAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        adapter = new FlickrAdapter(this, items);
        imageGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    // To avoid a memory leak on configuration change making it a inner class
    class FlickrDownloader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {



        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            FlickrGetter getter = new FlickrGetter();

            ArrayList<FlickrItem> newItems = getter.fetchItems();

            // clear the existing array
            items.clear();

            // add the new items to the array
            items.addAll(newItems);

            // is this correct ? - Wrong rebuilding the list view and should not be done in background
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

    public void search(View view) {
        // get the flickr data
        FlickrDownloader downloader = new FlickrDownloader();
        downloader.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I hope my answer though long will help in understanding some of the finer details.

Comment: May I know the reason why my explanation on the basis of an example for analogy sake has been down-voted, so that I also learn from it ?

Comment: first of all thanks for your reply, even though this topic is a bit old the core concepts remain still up to date. My initial question is not answered at all, you're giving an example and explain how it works, but the questions asks for differences between handler, asynctask and thread.

Comment: @80leaves ok i get the point now, i tried explaining on how I came to the conclusion of choosing one way over the other. Anyways, would love to hear your/others views on whether what I wrote is correct or if it can be improved further.

Answer (score 0):

**Thread**

When you start an app, a process is created to execute the code. To efficiently use computing resource, threads can be started within the process so that multiple tasks can be executed at the time. So threads allow you to build efficient apps by utilizing cpu efficiently without idle time.

In Android, all components execute on a single called main thread. Android system queue tasks and execute them one by one on the main thread. When long running tasks are executed, app become unresponsive.

To prevent this, you can create worker threads and run background or long running tasks.

**Handler**

Since android uses single thread model, UI components are created non-thread safe meaning only the thread it created should access them that means UI component should be updated on main thread only. As UI component run on the main thread, tasks which run on worker threads can not modify UI components. This is where Handler comes into picture. Handler with the help of Looper can connect to new thread or existing thread and run code it contains on the connected thread.

Handler makes it possible for inter thread communication. Using Handler, background thread can send results to it and the handler which is connected to main thread can update the UI components on the main thread.

**AsyncTask**

AsyncTask provided by android uses both thread and handler to make running simple tasks in the background and updating results from background thread to main thread easy.

Please see [android thread, handler, asynctask and thread pools](http://www.zoftino.com/android-threads-tutorial) for examples.

Answer (score -2):

`Handler` - is communication medium between threads. In android it is mostly used to communicate with main thread by creating and sending messages through handler

`AsyncTask` - is used to perform long running applications in a background thread. With n`AsyncTask` you get can do the operation in a background thread and get the result in the main thread of the application.

`Thread` - is a light weight process, to achieve concurrency and maximum cpu utilization. In android you can use thread to perform activities which does not touch UI of the app