# Async task or threads

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have the following task:

I have to do a `Wi-Fi scan`  and then send some `RSSs` to the a server to obtain a location from the server. After that I should display the location on a map.

I have one `activity` in my application. What is the best way to implement it? I haven't implemented a `thread nor AsyncTask` in android before. So I don't know a lot about it. I have read about threads and AsyncTask on android developer website. But I still can't understand everything.

I would appreciate it if anyone can tell me when its the best to use threads, and how AsynTask is different from threads and when to use `AsyncTask instead of threads`.

EDIT: the task that I have to implement should run only when the user click on actioBar item

.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964011/handler-vs-asynctask-vs-thread?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't understand the read documentation, I'd suggest starting with an `AsyncTask`, as it already implements a `Thread` when `doInBackground()` is fired and it already implements some mechanisms that you would probably have to implement by hand when using `Thread`s (concurrency, Thread start/stop processes, sending information to UI thread, ...).

However, you don't specify what exactly want to do. If you plan to do a long-running process, instead of `Thread`s or `AsyncTask`s, it's recommended using `Service` that would start a `Thread` as implementation, as contrary to popular beliefs, `AsyncTask`s are meant for short-lasting tasks.

In any case, if you're starting with this, I'd recommend using `AsyncTask` first, and when understood what it's doing and how, decide by yourself what's the best way to implement what you're planning to do: if running a `Service` with a `Thread` inside, a `Thread` itself or an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: the task that I mentioned is supposed to run for long time. I mean it should continuously detect the location and show it on the map. But as a start you recommend me to use AsyncTask in order to understand it right?

Comment: Correct. Probably the most smooth introduction to `Thread`s is an `AsyncTask` because it already has a "built-in" `Thread` and this way you can run it and see what happens, but as you comment it's a long-run task, at the end you should definitely migrate it to a `Service` with a `Thread` inside running it.

Comment: I have changed the design so that the task is done only when the user click on item in actionBar so AsyncTask would be enough?

Comment: The same answer applies here, if your goal is making an long-lasting task, set it to a `Service`. How it starts is not relevant here, just *how long* does it take to run is. If it will be a short task, an `AsyncTask` is enough, but if it's undetermined or a long task, switch it to a `Service`.