# Are there any drawbacks of using Thread instead of AsyncTask or Volley?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I'm new to android development but experienced in iOS development.  I see there are several purpose built classes for network communication.

I need to make several network connections in synchronous order, but of course dispatch them on a background thread asynchronously.  I was planning to wrap everything in a Thread runnable instead of using AsyncTask or Volley.

Are there going to be any issues with this?  Or any good reasons not to do it?

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

               // Run all my network connections in synchronous order here

        }
    }).start();
```

Thank-you for your time!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964011/handler-vs-asynctask-vs-thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, other than possibly needing to write some stuff yourself.

AsyncTask is a Thread.  It just has some code wrapped around it to make posting results to the UI thread easy.

Volley is a 3rd party library.  I have no clue what they use under the hood, but it will either be an AsyncTask or Thread.

So if you have some special use case that makes a Thread more convenient, go for it.  In fact its pretty common if you're doing direct socket IO.