# White color on Splash Screen

Tags: android, android-activity, splash-screen, oncreate, setcontentview

I've created a splash screen, and it works pretty fine at first, but after that, it shows me a white blank screen instead of my splash screen image file. I've no idea why that happens.

I tried to change my style.xml parent theme, but some of the themes crash my app, and only Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar works and gives me a blank white screen.

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Splash.java

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Thread ssThread = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(3000);
                    Intent startMainScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(startMainScreen);
                        finish();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        ssThread.start();
    }
}
```

Screen sequence, thread sleep time, and everything else works fine except that the image is not showing.

Comment: So, where are you showing your image file

Comment: Post your layout please.

Comment: You are not setting any content view in onCreate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your onCreate method, you forgot to add `setContentView(R.layout.splash);`

Comment: Thank you so much !! I accidentally deleted it just now while coding the layout.

Comment: If that worked, then please don't forget to accept my answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

YOU MISSING **setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_XML_NAME);**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.xxxx);


         /****** Create Thread that will sleep for 3 seconds *************/        
        Thread background = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    // Thread will sleep for 3 seconds
                    sleep(3*1000);

                    // After 5 seconds redirect to another intent
                    Intent startMainScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(startMainScreen);

                    //Remove activity
                    finish();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        };

        // start thread
        background.start();
}

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();

    }
}
```

Comment: @EHeng Great to hear. If helpful then accept please

Answer (score 2):

You need to add setContentView to your onCreate method.

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  /*
   *add setContentView here after super.onCreate( )
   */
  setContentView( R.layout.splash_layout);
  Thread ssThread = new Thread(){
   @Override
    public void run() {
     try {
      sleep(3000);
      Intent startMainScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
      startActivity(startMainScreen);
      finish();
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
   };
   ssThread.start();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set Layout in `onCreate` method of Splash activity like:

```
setContentView(R.layout.splash);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using thread and sleep function use Handler , and do some thing like this :

```
setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
int interval = 3000; // 3 second
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }, interval);
```

Comment: Is there any differences?

Comment: check this link and you will understand it  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964011/handler-vs-asynctask-vs-thread