# Start service periodically with AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

According to these examples: [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Starting-Background-Services) and [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html), I was trying to create Service which starts periodically.

First I created **Service**:

```
public class MonitorService extends IntentService {

     private static final String TAG = "MonitorService";

     public MonitorService() {
         super(TAG);
     }

     @Override
     protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
         Log.d("TAG", "Service method was fired.");
     }

}
```

Next I created **Receiver**:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "MyReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MyReceiver on receive");
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MonitorService.class);
        context.startService(i);
    }

}
```

I added starting method for this in **MainActivity**:

```
public void scheduleAlarm() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyReceiver.class);

        final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        // 1s is only for testing
        alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis, 1000, pIntent);
    }
```

which is calling of course in `onCreate` method.

And I didn't forget to change **AndroidManifest**:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:process=":remote" >
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name=".MonitorService"
        android:exported="false" />
```

And unfortunately the result is that nothing happens in my logs.

So I have two questions.

**QUESTION**

- How to solve issue with not starting service?
- If I add `scheduleAlarm` method to `onCreate` it will be calling every time I start my application, what is the best way to start this method only for the first time application is started?

**EDIT**

According to @Lasse hints, I started debugging, and realized that Log.d is not working, when I changed it to Log.i, information from MonitorService was logged.

But... debugging is not stoping on breaking point in MyReceiver, and changing Log.d to Log.i there didn't help. Of course MonitorService is firing, weird thing.

Also time with 1000 ms results in firing service every minute, maybe it's minimum time, and changing to AlarmManager.INTERVAL now doesn't matter.

**EDIT 2**

Finally I'm getting logs from both service and receiver. I had tried many times and after that it is working, but I don't know why.
But with that another problem has appeared - I'm getting warning when my Service is running

```
 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 21.787ms
```

I thought that Service is running background so it doesn't matter how long it is, should I concern about this warning?

Comment: But if your service is starting, what is the problem then?

And about the log level, in logcat you can choose the level of logs you want to see, so it should not matter if you choose Log.d or Log.i - but more what level is chosen in logcat :)

Comment: I edited question again :) And of course I know that I can choose level of logs.

Comment: It was not to be rude or anything, but saying that Log.d dont work is just not correct :)

Anyways, i dont know if you do other stuff in your code, but look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33114036/android-application-hangs-and-suspends-all-threads. 

Is your UI hanging? Or else i think you can safely ignore it, as this comment also says : "These sorts of messages are common to all Apps and you shouldn't be concerned. They are simply part of the Android framework logging and used to diagnose memory management issues and debugging problems" (see link, comment is there)

Comment: They are running when Activity is not visible and I'm getting this warn, so they shouldn't hanging UI, futhermore they are just getting user location.

Comment: Good, sounds like your problem is solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**

Regarding the first question :
See this from the [developer website](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#set)

```
  setInexactRepeating(), you have to use       one of the AlarmManager interval constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
```

So change your 1000 to use of of the constans

Regarding your other question you could override the application object and start it there. This way it is only called when launching the app.

Comment: The examples use a requestcode with differ from 0 - does that have any effect?

Comment: I tried with code like in first example, and still didn't work.

Comment: Edited answer - see above