# is Async Task = Thread + Handler in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Can some one tell me if I have understood it right that 
what we achieve using async task can be achieved using thread and handler?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handler vs AsyncTask vs Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964011/handler-vs-asynctask-vs-thread)

Answer (score 0):

They are pretty the same.But you can `cancle()` asynctask if you need.