# Views can't be updated after fragment changed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 2 fragments and one of them I'm trying to update some views after some data update. My views are updated fine when I remain in fragment when I have these views. After changed to another fragment my thread continues to work fine.
But after I return for the first fragment my views can't be updated.

```
myThread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public synchronized void run(){
            while( true ){
                try {
                    sleep( 2000 );
                    myActivity.runOnUiThread( new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            updateViews();
                        }
                    });

                } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

This is the update function:

```
private void updateViews(){
    textView.setText( _chronometerService.getTime() );
}
```

Notice my thread continues to update data, my issue is why views can't be updated.

Comment: Why are your using Threads like that?

Comment: @Stefan Just to update my views. Is there another way?

Comment: Handler for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964011/handler-vs-asynctask-vs-thread

Comment: @Stefan AsyncTask is for short operations. I don't think handlers fits in this case, because if I change to another fragment I cannot continuously update data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're creating a new fragment while switching?

Comment: As I said before.

Comment: I don't understand. Is it somehow unavoidable to create a new fragment object in your case? Is it not possible to keep the same object and only hide it using transactions?

Comment: I use FragmentTransaction.replace.commit for each fragment. They are changed when I press a button

Comment: Okay.  Not what I thought then.