# How clear RecyClerview Data after few seconds in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-recyclerview

I have a question regarding clearing recyclerview after few seconds in android. I tried doing this in a Thread but it didn't work for me. I used this code

```
public void cleardbView()
{
    final Thread countdown = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(15000);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.dbView);
                        arrayList.clear();
                        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
                        return;
                        }
                    });

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            return;
        }
    };
    countdown.start();
}
```

I am using this code in the section where I am adding data. The method is too big with all the conditions so I will put here only pseudo code(I tried to simplify it as much as I could :D )

```
if(conditions)
{
    insertData();
}
if(inserted)
{
    cleardbView(); 
}
```

Comment: no need to alter adapter again and again .. just add and clear data from your arraylist and then  notify the adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**`yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifydatasetchanged) after Clearing your list `arrayList.clear();`

> **`Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`**

- Notify any registered observers that the data set has changed.

Try this

```
public void cleardbView()
{
    final Thread countdown = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(15000);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.dbView);
                        arrayList.clear();
                        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
                        yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        return;
                        }
                    });

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            return;
        }
    };
    countdown.start();
}
```

Comment: Yeeees.. this helped... I need to check this in some sheets :)

Comment: yes I know I just have to wait untill 10 minutes lasts

Comment: Handler is better than using thread in android , check out my solution I have included the difference between them , sorry for disturbance :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a better and shorter implementation of your problem, and handlers are background threads that provide you ability to communicate with the UI // check here for more explanation about threads and handlers [Handler vs AsyncTask vs Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964011/handler-vs-asynctask-vs-thread)

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
int delay = 2000; //milliseconds

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
       RecyclerViewAdapterDataList.clear();
       RecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}, delay);
```

Comment: Isn't that a some kind of delegate?

Comment: I am sorry, but what do you mean? I didn't understand

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_(object-oriented_programming)   try to check this... very nice type of "not thread" programming :)

Comment: oh no handlers are background threads , and they are better than using the basic thread (Thread) which is given in first solution

Comment: Oh ok... I'll try that next time.. for my solution is better to use thread instead for now :)... thx I am upvoting your suggestion :)